# jquery $(this) returns [object object] instead of DOM reference

Tags: jquery, dom, this

In this situation

```
$(document).on('click', '.photo-actions .photo-link', function () {

   console.log($(this));

});
```

`$(this)` retrurns `[object object]` instead of DOM refference for an element which is clicked.
Why is this the case and how to get the DOM reference?
and if i write `$(this).attr('id');` it returns the id of element which it should.

Comment: you should use console.log(JSON.stringify($(this))); if you use chrome, you can write console.log("%o", $(this));

Comment: try: `$('.photo-actions .photo-link').on('click', function() {`

Answer (score 3):

To get the DOM element use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
 $(this).get(0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it normally return the element. I think it usually does?

Comment: jQuery selectors return jQuery object. To get the actual DOM you need to use .get()

Comment: @Dušan inside event callback function `this` is targeted element reference, means if element have `id` attribute then you can get id `this.id` etc

Comment: @Dušan $(this) will always return a jQuery object.

Comment: I think you're confusing `this` vs `$(this)`. The latter is a jquery object and returns an object containing all attributes that is accessible by jQuery methods (eg `.next()`, `.text()` and etc). You can see that by checking the console log and expanding the `[object object]` returned.

Comment: @MikaTuupola jQuery initialization ofcause returns new jQuery objects but the context in event bindings in jQuery always refers to the DOM node. No reason to initialize an jQuery object and then get the first value.

Comment: Yes I know. I was answering to the question.

Answer (score 3):

$(this) returns [object object] because it's a jquery object.Try console.log(this), you will get the
dom element you need.

Comment: A few years late, but this saved me today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use either simply 'this' for the DOM reference, or '$(this)[0]'. The value of '$(this)' is a jQuery object that provides you with all of the jQuery functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`this` **IS** the DOM Element. By wrapping it inside a `$` function call you obtain an object that inherits from `jQuery.prototype`.

Therefore, in order to get the id, you can do both: `this.id` or `$(this).attr("id")`.
If you would have received a jQuery object, you could have extracted the DOM element by using `$myObj.get(0)` or `$myObj[0]`, but it is not the case for you.

Comment: Not inherits from `jQuery.prototype` but is an instance of jQuery.

Comment: JS doesn't have the classical OO model, there are no such things as classes (or at least not in the traditional way of thinking).
In JS objects inherit from prototypes. When you do `new F()`, you create a new object that gets an iternal link (`[[Prototype]]`) to `F.prototype`. That link is used to travel the prototype chain in order to lookup a property names. In fact, when you do `o instanceof F`, you actually ask if `F.prototype` can be found along the `o`'s prototype chain.

Comment: Also, when you do `$(something)`, you will receive `new jQuery.fn.init(...)`, where `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype`. Also, `init.prototype = jQuery.fn`. That's why you can write plugins by adding methods on the `jQuery.fn` object.

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is a string representation of an Object in JavaScript.

Consider this:

```
alert({}); // [object Object]
alert(document.body); // Old browsers [object Object] newer browsers [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

If you see the string representation of an jQuery object or any other instance of a function it will be `[object Object]`.

Try fiddeling around with this:

```
String({}); // [object Object]
// Internally .toString is called:
var myObj = {};
myObj.toString(); // [object Object]
```

---

**TLDR:** You have no errors!